# Authenticate user using Active Directory/Windows authentication in MS Access 2007

Tags: winforms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

We have application built on MSAccess 2007. We want to add a new user login concept for this application.
I want to Authenticate user using Active Directory/Windows authentication.I want create a log file for this user.  (like we do for .net applications using forms authentication)
How do I do that on MS Access 2007.

Furthermore this application runs 24 hours, it will not be shutdown.  There can be multiple users using this application.
As I said this application is used 24/7, There are multiple shifts running and different users  login and logout.
During the user login and logout session, we need to keep track of the log for a particular user.
This application uses SQL server 2005 as database server.
Your advise is a great help for me, to develop this kind of module on MS Access 2007

Comment: I don't believe you can do what you're asking for. Using the Windows user logon (AD is not something special -- it's just a UI to NTFS users/security) you'll have to force the user to log off Windows and log back on.

Comment: Same(?) question for old versions of Access: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1425893/321973

Comment: Maybe related: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316748/how-to-authenticate-against-the-active-directory-by-using-forms-authentication-and-visual-c-.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the user has to log on to the pc, then you can simply grab their logon by using the code from http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0008.htm:

> ```vb
> ' This code was originally written by Dev Ashish.
> ' It is not to be altered or distributed,
> ' except as part of an application.
> ' You are free to use it in any application,
> ' provided the copyright notice is left unchanged.
> '
> ' Code Courtesy of
> ' Dev Ashish
> '
> Private Declare Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
>     "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
>
> Function fOSUserName() As String
> ' Returns the network login name
> Dim lngLen As Long, lngX As Long
> Dim strUserName As String
>     strUserName = String$(254, 0)
>     lngLen = 255
>     lngX = apiGetUserName(strUserName, lngLen)
>     If ( lngX > 0 ) Then
>         fOSUserName = Left$(strUserName, lngLen - 1)
>     Else
>         fOSUserName = vbNullString
>     End If
> End Function
> ```

And, the following is a vbs script, but it should work in Access just fine also:

[Displays Group Membership and Active Directory Location](http://msmvps.com/blogs/ad/archive/2008/12/15/script-that-displays-group-membership-and-active-directory-location.aspx)

> The following code can be run to display the group membership of an
>   Active Directory group and also let you know each member’s LDAP
>   Distinguished Name.  The output will name the text file the group name
>   and will include all the members and their location in Active
>   Directory.  Just copy this into a txt file and rename to .vbs  Enjoy!
>
> ```vb
> Set objGroup = GetObject(“LDAP://cn=GroupName,ou=OUName,DC=DomainName,DC=local“)
> Set objFileSystem = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)
> Set objFile = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(objGroup.Get(“name”) & ” – Members.txt“, 2, True, 0)
> For Each objMember in objGroup.Members
>   objFile.WriteLine objMember.Get(“sAMAccountName”) & VbTab & _
>     objMember.Get(“cn”) & VbTab & _
>     objMember.Parent
> Next
> Set objFile = Nothing
> Set objFileSystem = Nothing
> Set objGroup = Nothing
> ```

Comment: Thank you Albert D. Kallal.  
Its works fantastic. Yes I actually wanted to know the network userid.  I can log the details when ever the user is logged in and logged out.  Thanks it is a great help.   Can we also maintain sessions timeout in Access please, as we do in .net environment.

Answer (score 0):

In C#.Net use

```
Console.WriteLine("UserName: {0}", Environment.UserName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA in Access it's pretty easy.

```
Dim User As String
    Let User = Application.UserName
Dim arrUser
    Let arrUser = split(User, ",")
    User = arrUser(1)
    arrUser = split(User, "@")
    User = arrUser(0)
```

This seems to work for me in my VBA app.